# Как получить список пользователей, не нарушив ООП?

Tags: php, ооп

Всем привет
Интересует такой вопрос:

Есть класс User, в нём реализованы методы add (добавляет юзера в БД), get(получает юзера из бд).

С вызовом проблем нет: создаю экземпляр класса, далее
$user->add(параметры); и тд

Возник вопрос:
если мне нужно получать всех пользователей из БД, то как это сделать так, чтобы не нарушить ООП?

Если внутри User прописать getAll, то как-то странно, что юзер получает всех юзеров

Возможно, нужно использовать новый класс UserList? Или какие рекомендации в таком случае?

Comment: сделайте статический метод

Comment: Пока писал понял, что и метод add в классе User не корректен скорее всего. Мы же добавляем юзера в список юзеров. А в классе по логике должны быть только изменение параметров и работа с ними?

Comment: У меня весь класс был написан в статике, но прочитал, что такой подход вызывает слишком много проблем с зависимостями и хочу передать всё под чистое ООП

Comment: чтобы не нарушить ооп, нужно разделить класс на два - собственно юзер, который вообще ничего не знает про базу данных, и userMapper - который занимается получением и сохранением объектов класса юзер в БД. Вот в этом втором классе иметь метод взятьВсех очень даже уместно. надо почитать про паттерн Data Mapper

Comment: @Ипатьев спасибо за наводку с Data Mapper. Ушел копаться :)

Comment: @Ипатьев можно уточнить? Вот у меня есть условный UserMapper, он получил данные по юзерам, например: $um = new UserMapper($pdo); $users = $um->getAll(); Это ведь никак не привязано к самому классу User? Или надо для каждого юзера создавать экземпляр класса (массив юзеров будет использован для вывода на страницу в таблицу)?

Comment: UserMapper должен возвращать массив объектов User. И таким образом он *привязан* к классу User

Comment: не понял вопроса. зачем cоздавать маппер на каждого юзера? А, главное, кто их будет создавать? UserMapperMapper?

Comment: @splash58 спасибо

Comment: @Ипатьев спасибо, splash58 уже ответил выше

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите прям совсем по ООП, то как вариант:

```php
class User{

}

class UserCollection
{
    private $users = [];
    public function __construct(... $users)
    {
        foreach ($users as $user)
        {
            if(is_array($user))
            {
                array_walk($user,[$this,'add']);
            }
            else{
                $this->add($user);
            }
        }
    }

    private function add(User $user)
    {
        $this->users[] = $user;
    }
}

interface UserRepositoryInterface{
    public function get(): User;
    public function getAll(): UserCollection;
}
```

Comment: какая-то странная магия с is_array(). С одной стороны строгая типизация, а с другой у нас метод не знает, какие данные обрабатывает

Comment: @Ипатьев предложите свой вариант

Comment: ну вообще я подумал что наверное да, в отсутствие дженериков тут действительно, других вариантов особо и нет